# service selector vs deployment selector matchlabels

Tags: kubernetes

I understand that services use a selector to identify which pods to route traffic to by thier labels.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Thats all well and good.

Now what is the difference between this selector and the one of the `spec.selector` from the deployment. I understand that it is used so that the deployment can match and manage its pods.

I dont understand however why i need the extra `matchLabels` declaration and cant just do it like in the service. Whats the use of this semantically?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the `Service`'s `spec.selector`, you can identify which pods to route traffic to only by their labels.

On the other hand, in the `Deployment`'s `spec.selector` you have two options to decide on which node the pods will be scheduled on, which are: `matchExpressions`, `matchLabels`.

Comment: I don't thing this make sense... I have deployments with `spec.selector` that is not defined in nodes and the service is scheduled anyway... there is a specific config for node selector in deployment at `spec.template.spec.nodeSelector`

Comment: https://medium.com/@zwhitchcox/matchlabels-labels-and-selectors-explained-in-detail-for-beginners-d421bdd05362 
hi @ton can you check this link whether it answer to above question

Answer (score 14):

### How Deployment uses spec.selector

When a `Deployment` is changed, a new `ReplicaSet` is created. The `ReplicaSet` is responsible to manage the Pods. It uses the `spec.selector` to know what Pods it should manage.

Example:

If the `replicas: 1` is changed in the `Deployment` to e.g. `replicas: 2` a new `ReplicaSet` is created, and it *observes* the Pods using `spec.selector` to match Pods with matching labels. It only see 1 replica initially, but its desired state is now `replicas: 2` so it is responsible for creating additionally one Pod from the `template` in the `Deployment`.

#### Selector syntax

There is two ways to declare the `labels` under the `spec.selector` in `Deployment.

- matchLabels - you declare the labels
- matchExpressions - you write an expression for labels

See `kubectl explain deployment.spec.selector` for full explanation of `spec.selector` alternatives.

### Labels and Selectors

[Labels and Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) is a generic concept in Kubernetes and is used in multiple places. Another example is how you can filter what resources you want to see or use with `kubectl`. E.g. you can select the Pods for an app with:

```
kubectl get pod -l=app=myappname
```

(if your Pods is labelled with `app: myappname`.

Comment: that didnt answer my question in the slightest

Comment: It explained the `spec.selector`. The `matchLabels` is the syntax of the selector, since also `matchExpressions` is available. See `kubectl explain deployment.spec.selector` for a full description of the `selector` alternatives.

Comment: And I updated the answer with that. Both `matchExpressions` and `matchLabels` is possible.

Answer (score 10):

> why i need the extra matchLabels declaration and cant just do it like in the service. Whats the use of this semantically?

Because `service` spec only support *equality-based* selectors and the `deployment` is a newer resource that supports two syntax (*equality-based* and *set-based*).

> The API currently supports two types of selectors: equality-based and set-based. A label selector can be made of multiple requirements which are comma-separated. In the case of multiple requirements, all must be satisfied so the comma separator acts as a logical AND (&&) operator.
> [Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors)

The `Service` spec uses just the "equality-based" label selector syntax.

> Newer resources, such as Job, `Deployment`, `ReplicaSet`, and `DaemonSet`, support set-based requirements...
> [Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements)

My understanding is that earlier the only supported syntax was the equality-based one, like we have on the `service` spec, and that now, when the resource you are using supports the new syntax, you are required to use `matchLabels` or `matchExpressions`.

Comment: This is the best answer for OP's question. Nicely put and right on point.

Comment: "Newer resources, such as Job, Deployment, ReplicaSet, and DaemonSet, support set-based requirements" matchExpressions we can also set it on Pod for nodeAffinity at spec.affinity.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelctorTerms